# How to logout user from pusher

Tags: javascript, pusher, pusher-js

I have a single page application with a single pusher instance.

This pusher instance is being subscribed to 3 channels:

- `broadcast` (public channel available for everyone)
- `user-1` (private channel available only to user with id 1)
- `article-123` (public channel since user is currently browsing article with id 123)

I did this running following commands:

```
pusher.signin();
pusher.subscribe('broadcast').bind(...);
pusher.subscribe('private-user-1').bind(...);
pusher.subscribe('article-123').bind(...);
```

Now user clicks logout button and then logins into another account.
I can easily do:

```
pusher.unsubscribe('private-user-1');
pusher.subscribe('private-user-2').bind(...);
```

but what about `signin()`?
How can I tell pusher that the user changed without leaving the other two channels?
I dont see a `signout()` function in the API.

Comment: Do you have a function that returns the User ID? A method like `getUserID()`? If yes, please post the code.

Comment: @AztecCodes not sure what you are asking for. UserId is returned from backend from the endpoint configured as `userAuthentication` in Pusher constructor. And the `1` in `private-user-1` is stored in a local variable (also returned from backend during authorization)